# Strange blocky/interlaced textures on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 games

Tags: 20.04, games, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen, visual-artifacts

I have had this problem for every game that seems to be OpenGL-based. It seems to be interlacing or scrambling blocks of pixels around.
Here is an example with Neverputt.

[image]

Specs:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 3200U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx x 4
- Graphics: AMD RAVEN2

This worked on my old Nvidia laptop with the same OS. Does this happen with any of you non-AMD users?

Answer (score 0):

Disable texture compression, enable lowest quality settings, make it fullscreen, and fit the screen to your resolution.